# How do I do OAuth1 in PHP the way this Perl code does it?

Tags: php, perl, rest, oauth

I am trying to convert a Perl script that makes REST calls to PHP. I'm having trouble with 2 lines in the below code.

```
    my $url = 'https://awebsite.com/apilink';
    my $oauthurl = $url.'?'.$xoauth.'='.$oauthmail;
    my $client = REST::Client->new();
    my %retval = ();

    my $request = Net::OAuth->request('consumer')->new(
        consumer_key => $oauthkey,
        consumer_secret => $oauthsec,
        request_url =>  $url,
        request_method => 'GET',
        signature_method => $oauthsig,
        timestamp => time,
        nonce => nonce(),
        extra_params => {
           $xoauth => $oauthmail
        }
    );
    $request->sign;
    $client->addHeader('Content-type' => 'application/json');
    $client->addHeader('Authorization' => $request->to_authorization_header);
    $client->addHeader('Accept-Encoding' => 'identity');

    $client->GET( $oauthurl );
```

These are the lines that are giving me trouble.

```
    extra_params => { $xoauth => $oauthmail }
    $client->addHeader('Authorization' => $request->to_authorization_header);
```

I am unsure how to deal with the HASH used with the 'extra_params' or the dereference in the header creation.

Comment: I doubt you can translate that literally. You'd have to look at the implementation in PHP that does the OAuth to decide how to give it extra parameters, and at the client implementation you're using to learn how to add additional headers to a request. The `$request->to_authorization_header` does what it says on the box, it produces the oauth header, so you'd have to find some tool that does that, or build it yourself. Stuff like this with advanced abstraction can usually not be _translated_ or _converted_. It can be rewritten in a different language though.

Comment: Thank you for the input @simbabque. This script is accessing a REST server using OAuth 1.0 and while there is a lot out there about that version most of the links have good information but because they are so old the libraries associated with them are gone. You are probably correct saying that a will have to build my own tool to get this done.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot say which library is the right pick for OAuth in PHP. I sincerely hope you do not have to roll your own. There will be tools for it, but of course Stack Overflow is the wrong place for Software Recommendations. A quick google gave me http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php, which sounds pretty much out of the box.

Comment: I did see the link in your last comment and do need to look into it further.  If I could I'd give you an up vote for your help. But being new my reputation is not high enough. Until then I can only thank you again!

Comment: Don't worry about that. Voting on comments doesn't give reputation anyway, it just makes it easier to see useful comments first. Once you figure it out, feel free to self-answer the question with some appropriate PHP code. I'll edit the title to give it a visibility bump in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks again ... I have much to learn.